# JPA/HQL native query from string

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

For example I have this query part as predefined temp.

```
String temp = "select st from xxxx st where "
```

Later there is if else operator.

```
if (c>v)temp += "yyy is null";
else temp += "yyy = 2";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(temp);
```

Stack trace exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: If something table and schema is predefined, and the em is EntityManager

Comment: If you are adding conditions to the `WHERE` clause, you should use `AND`.

Comment: Make your mind up if doing a "native" query or a JPQL query; you currently create JPQL yet invoke as native.

Comment: Sorry for being a beginner...actually it does not matter which type of query

Comment: Anyway, looked more at JPQL queries and made that one, thanks.

Comment: If it "doesn't matter which type of query" then please decide which one the question is for and then people can focus on that type. If this is native then your query should be SQL, so please just give the SQL you are passing in to "createNativeQuery". It's nothing to do with being a beginner or otherwise, make the problem definition clear please then you'll get the solution

Answer (score 0):

Multiple clauses in the where statement are separated by `and`:

```
else temp += " and yyy = 2"
```

Also native SQL queries do not use the alias within the select clause to select all columns they use `*`.

```
String temp = "select * from xxxx st where "
```

Comment: @undefined Mistyped something in the question? Or the actual code? Is your problem solved?

Comment: In question, added all what I missed

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that, just put the `yyy` variable inside the if condition, as it is duplicated in your query

```
String temp = "select st from xxxx st where "

if (c>v)
    temp += "yyy is null";
else 
    temp += "yyy = 2"

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you forget the `st.` identifier before the `yyy`
or maybe because you just select `st` but should select `st.*`

It should be `select st.* from xxxx st where st.yyy is null`

Please trace the generated SQL with hibernate property `show_sql = true` and post it here